# Using RegEx to find a specific pattern of text

Tags: regex

I have the following text.....

```
('virtualMachines_20160810_VM02_name'),'2016710113655.vhd'))]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite"
          },
          "dataDisks": []
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_20160810_VM02_name')]",
          "adminUsername": "marc.kean",
          "windowsConfiguration": {
            "provisionVMAgent": true,
            "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
          },
          "secrets": [],
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('virtualMachines_20160810_VM02_adminPassword')]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_20160810_vm02308_name'))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
```

I am trying to use RegEx to match exactly a section of this text. The section I want to match from is the entire line containing the text **"osProfile"** (including all whitespace at the beginning/end of the line) down to and including the entire line (including any whitespace) the line just above **"networkProfile"**

This is what I have so far, but this matches two capture groups, I only want specifically the text i have specified.

```
\s*"osProfile[\w|\W]*},(\s*"networkProfile")
```

I also have this:

```
((\s*"osProfile[\w|\W]*?},)([\w|\W
```

Comment: is this a JSON file? isn't it easier to get it as an object than making a regexp to extract it ?

Answer (score 1):

not sure what your use case is for using regex, but is this what you want:

```
\s*"osProfile":\s*\{[^\}]+\}[^\}]+\},
```

https://regex101.com/r/qA1nQ1/2

```
\s*"osProfile":\s*\{
```

will get you the first line

```
[^\}]+\}
```

will get you everything up till the first }

```
[^\}]+\},
```

will get you everything up till the second } followed by the ,